# I can't find object in GET url,how to fetch data without object. I want to use title from articles with json parser

Tags: java, android

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 80249,
"articles": [
    {
        "source": {
            "id": null,
            "name": "Newsbtc.com"
        },
        "author": "Aayush Jindal",
        "title": "Ethereum Price Weekly Analysis – ETH/USD Bearish Below $870"
```

//in android show below code

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(url, new 
Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("NEWS Activity",response);
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    NewsPojo newsPojo=new NewsPojo();

                    newsPojo.setTitle(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                    list.add(newsPojo);
                }
                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Comment: post your full json response

Comment: https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=2a3bce5713494ef98b7dd8cc5a72ba54 @Munir

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

        String title = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
        //then do what you want to do with title
    }
```

I would however recommend you to use Gson and retrofit to parse and retrieve data as its much faster and easier to do with less mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("NEWS Activity",response);
                try {

```
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
                List<NewsPojo> newsPojoList = new ArrayList<>();
                NewsPojo newsPojo=new NewsPojo();
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    newsPojo.setTitle(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                    newsPojoList.add(newsPojo);
                }

                newsAdapter=new NewsAdapter(MainActivity.this,newsPojoList);
                recyclerNews.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

This is the right answer